# CakePHP one form for multiple models does not validate properly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

So I have two models, that are `Company` and `User`. Here are the relations:

Company:

```
public $hasMany = array(
'User' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
)
```

User:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
    )
```

And there is a form were both instances are being created. The problem is that only the `Company` fields are being validated and `User` is not. Even though the validation rules for just creating or editting a `User` work perfect. Here is the form in question:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Company', array('action'=>'register'));?>

     echo $this->Form->input('Company.name', array('label'=>__('Company name*')));
     echo $this->Form->input('Company.address', array('label'=>__('Address*')));
     echo $this->Form->input('Company.city', array('label'=>__('City*')));
     echo $this->Form->input('User.0.name', array('label'=>__('Name*')));
     echo $this->Form->input('User.0.email', array('label'=>__('Email*')));
     echo $this->Form->input('User.0.email_confirmation', array('label'=>__('Email confirmation')));


echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Save', 'onclick'=>'disableSubmit(this)'));
```

I am fully aware of the `validate only` option, but I wonder what is the proper way to make validation work.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

As requested, I provide the Model logic as well:

```
    public function registerCompany($data){


    unset($this->User->validate['company_id']);

    if($this->saveAll($data, array('validate'=>'only'))){
    if($this->saveAssociated($data)){                                                                                                     
        return true;
    }
}else{

             return false;
         }
    }
```

Here are some of the validation rules of User model, there are two different validation types for REST service and for web client, so this is for the web client only. NOTE: it works all good on single  user create/edit:

$this->validate = array(

```
            'name'=>array(
        'Insert user name'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'Insert user name',
            'last'=>false
        )
         )
```

Comment: how have you declared the validation in your model ? Can you show us this code too ?

Comment: Dear @Miam84, I have just updated the question with the model's logic. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is your controller's code (helpfull too). I meant the code of the `User model` in your `Model/User.php` file. There you should have setted the $validate array to valid your model

Comment: That was the code from Company's model. I have just updated the question with validation rules, that work alright for single user create/edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to validate:

Suppose you are saving the data from "Company Controller".

```
    if( $this->Company->saveAll(array('validate'=>only)){
          //your save logic here
    } else {
         //here form has some validation errors.
         debug($this->Company->validationErrors);
    }
```

Try this any reply....

Same you can do with "User"

```
    if( $this->User->saveAll(array('validate'=>only)){
          //your save logic here
    } else {
         //here form has some validation errors.
         debug($this->User->validationErrors);
    }
```

And

In form use this for user data:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.name', array('label'=>__('Name*')));
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I am fully aware of this option, but it does not look like a natural way of applying the validation.

Comment: I found the one error in form creation I have added it to answer. Have look. Or just tell me why you have added the "0" there. May you have added it with some other purpose.

Comment: That is the natural way of creating a form for HasMany in cakePHP you can read all about it in the cake docummentaion.

Comment: So are you going to add the multiple user at a time for the company data?

Comment: Not in this particular case, but it may be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

`saveAll` is a wrapper of `saveMany` and `saveAssociated`. So you don't have to call both methods.

Then, according to the Cake's doc, to unset a validation you should use the syntax : `$this->Model->AssociatedModel->validate...`

Should look like this :

```
public function registerCompany($data){
    unset($this->Company->User->validate['company_id']);
    if($this->Company->saveAssociated($this->request->data)){                                                                                 
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }    
}
```